# Error in mydata[[vars[i]]] out of bounds in windRose

Tags: r

i am trying to plot windrose in R, but for all variable, it is given same error. 
Here is my code,

```
Bandirma_MGM <-read_excel("~/Desktop/Bandırma_Kuzey_Mendirek_Fener_MGM.xlsx")

speed <- Bandirma_MGM$`Saatlik Ortalama Rüzgar Hızı (m/sn)`
direction <- Bandirma_MGM$`Ortalama Rüzgar Yönü  (°)`
facet <- Bandirma_MGM$`Ortalama Rüzgar Yön Adı`
Bandirma_MGM$date <- as.Date(with(Bandirma_MGM, paste(Yıl, Ay, Gün,sep="-")), "%Y-%m-%d")
date <- Bandirma_MGM$date

windRose(speed, direction, facet, date)
```

Comment: facet is name of directions and i wanted to add date on the plot if it is possible. Thank you for helping, it works )

Comment: Hi Elis - can you provide some idea of what your are trying to produce? A windrose that is faceted by date will not be useful. Are you looking to facet by a range of dates? Can you give us this:    
`x <- Bandirma_MGM[1:24,];
    dump("x", file = stdout())`